# Can't make XPath to work with complex namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

Let's start with an XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/" timeStamp="2009-11-26T15:21:36Z" uuid="02334fb6-3ae8-4094-9279-29ff59fc5bc8">
    <config xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xci/2.6/">
        ...
    </config>
    <template xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.6/">
        <subform name="movie" w="196.85mm">
            <field name="duration" y="11.7mm" x="2.175mm" w="62mm" h="9mm">
                ...
            </field>
            <field name="imdb" y="11.7mm" x="65.675mm" w="62mm" h="9mm">
                ...
            </field>
            ...
            <subform name="directors" layout="tb" x="2.175mm" y="30.75mm" w="95.25mm">
                ...
                <field name="director" w="91.075mm" h="9mm">
                    ...
                </field>
                ...
            </subform>
            ...
        </subform>
        ...
    </template>
    ...
</xdp:xdp>
```

(For those who are wondering, it's a simplified version of the XFA document of the PDF used in [this iText example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165).)

Now I want to get all the `<field>` elements in a `NodeList`, and `XPath` would be perfect for the purpose:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String p) {
        return "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.6/";
    }
    public String getPrefix(String arg0) {return null;}
    public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String arg0) {return null;}    
});
NodeList fields = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//field", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now that doesn't work, the result is empty. I've tried returning `null` in `getNamespaceURI` too; also returning `"http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/"` if the prefix is `"xdp"` and `null` otherwise.

I've also tried getting the `<template>` element manually and using evaluate from that node, with the above `NamespaceContext` or with `getNamespaceURI` returning `null`...

Nothing seems to work with this over-complicated system, and I don't want to keep on trying without getting a clue of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yours code with simplified xml worked fine, I have checked. Parsed with DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a prefix in your path e.g. `//df:field` and then of course make sure that prefix is bound to the namespace URI e.g.

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String p) {
      if (p.equals("df")) {
        return "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.6/";
      }
    }
    public String getPrefix(String arg0) {return null;}
    public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String arg0) {return null;}    
});
```

Comment: That's one of those "a-ha!" moments! Thank you. P.S.: fix it with `p.equals("df")` and it's perfect ;)

Comment: Sorry about the use of "==" to compare strings, I am more of a Javascript or C# coder than a Java coder. I have edited the code sample to use `equals`.

Comment: Yes, I'm more a Javascript developer too and admittedly the way Java compare strings is quite jarring.